# send data to server every minute (For check status user)

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

For check status user i should send some data to server every 5 minutes with retrofit2.

Of course, this information should be sent when the user is in the app

This means that when the user is out of the application, there is no need to send something to the server

What is the best way to do this?

For connection to server i use retrofit2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to use Android's work manager to ping your server with http request. You can create initial OneTimeWorkRequest when user logins and with in each execution create a new OneTimeWorkRequest with 5 minutes delay. When user exits the app cancel all the work request.

See the Jetpack Library: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager

Another solution for which you need to make changes in your architecture is to use Sockets with library like SocketIO. Connect the socket from your app when user login notifying server that user is online. When socket disconnect server can mark user offline: https://socket.io/blog/native-socket-io-and-android/

One other solution is to use Firebase Realtime database for presence system. Firebase has nice example of how to do this: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2013/06/how-to-build-presence-system.html

Comment: with work manager you can only execute task every 15 minutes and onwards . it wont work if window is less than 15 mins

Comment: We can use OneTimeWorkRequest and after the execution of task create next OneTimeWorkRequest. This way we don't need to use interval request and limited to 15 minutes window.

Answer (score 0):

You can write this code in service and make network call every 5 minutes using handler or RxJava;

```
public class YourService extends Service{

 public final Handler handler = new Handler();




   @Override
    public void onCreate() {

    makeCallEvery5Min();
    }



private void makeCallEvery5Min(){
 runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

            // execute call here 
            }

             handler.postDelayed(runnable, delay);

}


}


}
```

**RXJava**

```
  private void makeCallEvery5min() {
        Observable.interval(0, 5, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(v -> your_network_call() );
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

## May help you below approach

If user is log in, should have user id.

Now try to check for user id of particular user in user log in session.

Note: below code should be added in web page(jsp or servlet)--.

1. Single User Approach:if(userId==Session.getUserId(userId)){response.refresh(5);//write code to send data to server using retrofit2.}
2. MultiUser Approach: multiple users log in.if(Session.getUsers()!=null){response.refresh(5);//write code to send data to server using retrofit2 }